# Not able to change network settings on Kubuntu 20.10

Tags: networking, kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 20.10 on a desktop machine. Previously I had set my Ethernet to use a manual IP address (192.168.0.114). On the new network the subnet is 192.168.1.XXX, so I tried to set the network adapter to automatic and hit Save in the Network Settings screen. After disconnecting the cable and reconnecting it, it reverts back to the Manual IP address. Also when I run `hostname -I` it shows the old IP address.

Not sure what is going on here. Is there a way to completely wipe the network settings? Or is there a file I can edit to change the network settings rather than through the GUI?

Result of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Result of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`cat /etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       linuxamd

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

`cat /etc/hostname`

```
linuxamd
```

`hostname -I`

```
192.168.0.114 192.168.1.83 2600:1700:5ef0:67b0:5771:7bd0:b3d9:a26f 2600:1700:5ef0:67b0:febd:52a0:bd99:a94a 2600:1700:5ef0:67b0::2e 2600:1700:5ef0:67b0:f7c6:4441:3233:87ba 2600:1700:5ef0:67b0:6aba:cca1:cc53:2a06
```

EDIT (Sep 11, 2021): I can get it to work by running `sudo dhclient -r` and then `sudo dhclient`. It will still show the old static IP address and the new one. But I have to do that every time I restart the machine. So still not a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I ran `sudo grep -rIH 192.168.0.114` in `/etc`. It listed `dhcpcd.conf` file as having that value. In the file at the very bottom it was setting it as a static ip. See below:

```
interface enp4s0
    static ip_address=192.168.0.114/24
    static routers=192.168.0.1
    static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
```

I comment those 4 lines and restarted the machine. Now it picks up the right IP address from the router!

Answer (score 1):

In order to completely remove all previous network settings, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo rm -r /etc/NetworkMananager/system-connections/*
```

Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

You should be all set.

**EDIT**: Your interfaces file doesn't appear to be correct. Please change it to read:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but no luck. There are no files in system-connections folder now, but it still reverts to the static IP address. I did see an error message which stated `DHCP failed to start` for `Wired Interface (enp4s0)` after I ran the restart command on NetworkManager.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: I have added the results of those commands.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: After updating the interfaces file and rebooting, when I run `hostname -I` it now shows both the old and the new IP address. But it does not show up in Network Manager. This is how it was before. So if I restart network manager or unplug & plug the ethernet cable it will show the old IP address.

Comment: Let's have a look at `cat /etc/hosts` and also `cat /etc/hostname` Fascinating problem here!

Comment: Done, see edited post.